# Phinx migration Exception

Tags: php, migration, phinx

Im using the package  `"robmorgan/phinx": "^0.15"`

I've run into an issue with Phinx migration: when I run the command `phinx migrate` with the config file, an error occurs.

**Command:**

```
 vendor\bin\phinx migrate -c "Device/conf.php"
```

**Error message:**

```
TypeError: Phinx\Db\Adapter\PdoAdapter::createPdoConnection(): Argument #2 ($username) must be of type ?string, bool given, called in C:\Applications\wamp\www\migration\src\vendor\robmorgan\phinx\src\Phinx\Db\Adapter\MysqlAdapter.php on line 158 and defined in C:\Applications\wamp\www\migration\src\vendor\robmorgan\phinx\src\Phinx\Db\Adapter\PdoAdapter.php:85
Stack trace:
#0 C:\Applications\wamp\www\migration\src\vendor\robmorgan\phinx\src\Phinx\Db\Adapter\MysqlAdapter.php(158): Phinx\Db\Adapter\PdoAdapter->createPdoConnection('mysql:host=;dbn...', false, false, Array)
#1 C:\Applications\wamp\www\migration\src\vendor\robmorgan\phinx\src\Phinx\Db\Adapter\PdoAdapter.php(169): Phinx\Db\Adapter\MysqlAdapter->connect()
#2 C:\Applications\wamp\www\migration\src\vendor\robmorgan\phinx\src\Phinx\Db\Adapter\PdoAdapter.php(256): Phinx\Db\Adapter\PdoAdapter->getConnection()
#3 C:\Applications\wamp\www\migration\src\vendor\robmorgan\phinx\src\Phinx\Db\Adapter\PdoAdapter.php(277): Phinx\Db\Adapter\PdoAdapter->query('SELECT * FROM `...')
#4 C:\Applications\wamp\www\migration\src\vendor\robmorgan\phinx\src\Phinx\Db\Adapter\PdoAdapter.php(413): Phinx\Db\Adapter\PdoAdapter->fetchAll('SELECT * FROM `...')
#5 C:\Applications\wamp\www\migration\src\vendor\robmorgan\phinx\src\Phinx\Db\Adapter\PdoAdapter.php(385): Phinx\Db\Adapter\PdoAdapter->getVersionLog()
#6 C:\Applications\wamp\www\migration\src\vendor\robmorgan\phinx\src\Phinx\Db\Adapter\AdapterWrapper.php(206): Phinx\Db\Adapter\PdoAdapter->getVersions()
#7 C:\Applications\wamp\www\migration\src\vendor\robmorgan\phinx\src\Phinx\Migration\Manager\Environment.php(254): Phinx\Db\Adapter\AdapterWrapper->getVersions()
#8 C:\Applications\wamp\www\migration\src\vendor\robmorgan\phinx\src\Phinx\Migration\Manager.php(316): Phinx\Migration\Manager\Environment->getVersions()
#9 C:\Applications\wamp\www\migration\src\vendor\robmorgan\phinx\src\Phinx\Console\Command\Migrate.php(124): Phinx\Migration\Manager->migrate('dev', NULL, false)
#10 C:\Applications\wamp\www\migration\src\vendor\symfony\console\Command\Command.php(326): Phinx\Console\Command\Migrate->execute(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#11 C:\Applications\wamp\www\migration\src\vendor\symfony\console\Application.php(1063): Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#12 C:\Applications\wamp\www\migration\src\vendor\symfony\console\Application.php(320): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand(Object(Phinx\Console\Command\Migrate), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#13 C:\Applications\wamp\www\migration\src\vendor\robmorgan\phinx\src\Phinx\Console\PhinxApplication.php(69): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#14 C:\Applications\wamp\www\migration\src\vendor\symfony\console\Application.php(174): Phinx\Console\PhinxApplication->doRun(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput)) #15 C:\Applications\wamp\www\migration\src\vendor\robmorgan\phinx\bin\phinx(28): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run()
#16 C:\Applications\wamp\www\migration\src\vendor\bin\phinx(120): include('C:\\Applications...')
#17 {main}
```

**My conf file content :**

```
$conf = [
    "paths" => [
        "migrations" => __DIR__,
    ],
    "environments" => [
        "default_migration_table" => "phinxlog",
        "default_environment" => "dev",
        "dev" => [
            "adapter" => "mysql",
            "host" => getenv('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            "name" => getenv("DB_DATABASE_CATALOG_DEVICE"),
            "user" => getenv('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            "pass" => getenv('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            "charset" => "utf8",
            "collation" => "utf8_general_ci",
        ],
    ],
];
```